# Excel 2016 Installable ISAM

Tags: excel, ms-access, office-automation

I have an access 2007 application that exports data to an excel sheet and then opens the file.  One user has just upgraded Excel to 2016.  When it tries to export the file, I get the 'Could Not Find Installable ISAM' error.  The code is simple and works on every other computer at the location, but no one else has Excel newer than 2010.

I followed the advice in the Microsoft KB article about checking for and re-registering the ISAM file - it is there and it looks fine.  I repaired the office instillation and that did nothing as well.

My gut says that there needs to be a newer version of instruction to export with - I am using `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` which is for Excel 2010, but Access 2007 has nothing supported newer than that.  I don't have a version of Excel 2016 to test it on, but I can get on his computer from time to time.  Also, I don't want to have to upgrade to Access 2010 if at all possible.

Thanks!